# Как увеличить размер ContentPlaceHolder1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webforms

ContentPlaceHolder1 находится в MasterPage. Обрезает GridView. Как изменить размер ContentPlaceHolder1? Пробовал так, 0 реакции:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" style="height: 1000px;">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

и так

```
<div class="right-content" style="height: 1000px;">&nbsp;
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" style="height: 1000px;">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `asp:ContentPlaceHolder` не производит html.

Comment: Это дизайнер студии. Он не показывает реальной картины, страшно глючит, и дописывает мусор в код. Не пользуйтесь им. Пользуйтесь реальным браузером.

Comment: Изменил высоту дива содержащего ContentPlaceHolder с 100% до 1000px.(после редактирования придётся вернуть) За 100% он принимает именно размер окошка в конструкторе.